# Find closest/similar value(vector) inside a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

let's say I have the following numpy matrix (simplified):

```
matrix = np.array([[1, 1],
               [2, 2],
               [5, 5],
               [6, 6]]
              )
```

And now I want to get the vector from the matrix closest to a "search" vector:

```
search_vec = np.array([3, 3])
```

What I have done is the following:

```
min_dist = None
result_vec = None
for ref_vec in matrix:
    distance = np.linalg.norm(search_vec-ref_vec)
    distance = abs(distance)
    print(ref_vec, distance)
    if min_dist == None or min_dist > distance:
        min_dist = distance
        result_vec = ref_vec
```

The result works, but **is there a native numpy solution to do it more efficient?**
My problem is, that the bigger the matrix becomes, the slower the entire process will be.
Are there other solutions that handle these problems in a more elegant and efficient way?

Comment: Looks like School is back in session.  We probably need a conconical duplicate, [as this is the second question in six hours for this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360834/numpy-for-each-element-of-one-array-find-its-closest-point-in-another-array#comment91668598_52360834)

Comment: @Daniel F Feel free to edit my post in a way that it helps to prevent duplicates. Sry fo asking the same question again. I couldn't find it before posting this new question.

Comment: [Canonical Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366421/how-to-do-n-d-distance-and-nearest-neighbor-calculations-on-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`Cython-powered kd-tree` for quick nearest-neighbor lookup](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html), which is very efficient both memory-wise and with performance -

```
In [276]: from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

In [277]: matrix[cKDTree(matrix).query(search_vec, k=1)[1]]
Out[277]: array([2, 2])
```

**Approach #2**

With [`SciPy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
In [286]: from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

In [287]: matrix[cdist(matrix, np.atleast_2d(search_vec)).argmin()]
Out[287]: array([2, 2])
```

**Approach #3**

With [`Scikit-learn's` Nearest Neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) -

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1).fit(matrix)
closest_vec = matrix[nbrs.kneighbors(np.atleast_2d(search_vec))[1][0,0]]
```

**Approach #4**

With [`Scikit-learn's` kdtree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#kdtree-and-balltree-classes) -

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
kdt = KDTree(matrix, metric='euclidean')
cv = matrix[kdt.query(np.atleast_2d(search_vec), k=1, return_distance=False)[0,0]]
```

**Approach #5**

From [`eucl_dist`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist)  package  (disclaimer: I am its author) and following the  [`wiki contents`](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#prospective-method), we could leverage `matrix-multiplication` -

```
M = matrix.dot(search_vec)
d = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',matrix,matrix) + np.inner(search_vec,search_vec) -2*M
closest_vec = matrix[d.argmin()]
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. I will try that out. Are 3d vectors also possible with  scipy in that case?

Comment: Hey @Divakar, if I write a canonical duplicate question, would you help answer it?

Comment: @DanielF Sure! We could have a SO wiki answer post probably on it.

Comment: [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366421/how-to-do-n-d-distance-and-nearest-neighbor-calculations-on-numpy-arrays)